# with terraform version 13, I am getting error nvalid default value for variable in region params, how to fix that?

Tags: upgrade, terraform

variables.tf

```
variable "region" {
  default = "us-central1"
}

variable "zone" {
  description = "override default zone specified in region_params"
  default     = ""
}

variable "region_params" {
  description = "Map of default zones for each region. Can be overridden using the `zone`."
  type        = map(string)

  default = {
    asia-east1 = {
      zone = "asia-east1-b"
    }
    asia-east2 = {
      zone = "asia-east2-b"
    }
    asia-northeast1 = {
      zone = "asia-northeast1-b"
    }
    asia-south1 = {
      zone = "asia-south1-b"
    }
    asia-southeast1 = {
      zone = "asia-southeast1-b"
    }
    australia-southeast1 = {
      zone = "australia-southeast1-b"
    }
    europe-north1 = {
      zone = "europe-north1-b"
    }
    europe-west1 = {
      zone = "europe-west1-b"
    }
    europe-west2 = {
      zone = "europe-west2-b"
    }
    europe-west3 = {
      zone = "europe-west3-b"
    }
    europe-west4 = {
      zone = "europe-west4-b"
    }
    northamerica-northeast1 = {
      zone = "northamerica-northeast1-b"
    }
    southamerica-east1 = {
      zone = "southamerica-east1-b"
    }
    us-central1 = {
      zone = "us-central1-b"
    }
    us-east1 = {
      zone = "us-east1-b"
    }
    us-east4 = {
      zone = "us-east4-b"
    }
    us-west1 = {
      zone = "us-west1-b"
    }
    us-west2 = {
      zone = "us-west2-b"
    }
  }
}

variable "network" {
}

variable "instance_tags" {
  default = []
}

variable "ip_cidr_range" {
  description = "Subnetwork range - required"
}

variable "environment" {
  description = "The build environment tier"
  default     = "dev"
}

output "nat-gateway-ip" {
  value = module.nat.external_ip
}
```

./terraform0.13 init -reconfigure

> ```
> There are some problems with the configuration, described below.
>
> The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that
> Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.
> ╷
> │ Error: Invalid default value for variable
> │
> │   on variables.tf line 71, in variable "region_params":
> │   71:   default = {
> │   72:     asia-east1 = {
> │   73:       zone = "asia-east1-b"
> │   74:     }
> │   75:     asia-east2 = {
> │   76:       zone = "asia-east2-b"
> │   77:     }
> │   78:     asia-northeast1 = {
> │   79:       zone = "asia-northeast1-b"
> │   80:     }
> │   81:     asia-south1 = {
> │   82:       zone = "asia-south1-b"
> │   83:     }
> │   84:     asia-southeast1 = {
> │   85:       zone = "asia-southeast1-b"
> │   86:     }
> │   87:     australia-southeast1 = {
> │   88:       zone = "australia-southeast1-b"
> │   89:     }
> │   90:     europe-north1 = {
> │   91:       zone = "europe-north1-b"
> │   92:     }
> │   93:     europe-west1 = {
> │   94:       zone = "europe-west1-b"
> │   95:     }
> │   96:     europe-west2 = {
> │   97:       zone = "europe-west2-b"
> │   98:     }
> │   99:     europe-west3 = {
> │  100:       zone = "europe-west3-b"
> │  101:     }
> │  102:     europe-west4 = {
> │  103:       zone = "europe-west4-b"
> │  104:     }
> │  105:     northamerica-northeast1 = {
> │  106:       zone = "northamerica-northeast1-b"
> │  107:     }
> │  108:     southamerica-east1 = {
> │  109:       zone = "southamerica-east1-b"
> │  110:     }
> │  111:     us-central1 = {
> │  112:       zone = "us-central1-f"
> │  113:     }
> │  114:     us-east1 = {
> │  115:       zone = "us-east1-b"
> │  116:     }
> │  117:     us-east4 = {
> │  118:       zone = "us-east4-b"
> │  119:     }
> │  120:     us-west1 = {
> │  121:       zone = "us-west1-b"
> │  122:     }
> │  123:     us-west2 = {
> │  124:       zone = "us-west2-b"
> │  125:     }
> │  126:   }
> │
> │ This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint: element "asia-east2": string required.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it to us-central-1. You're formatting your regions wrong, you need a dash before the number. Additionally you don't need to specify a, b, or c since terraform gets the information from your subnet setting.

Comment: SOrry I didn't mention the cloud, GCP. For GCP it is the structure

Comment: On second though you're possibly not using a map correctly and might be defining it wrong.

Also... I wouldn't define zone as a variable. A map is like an array that uses names instead of numbers, so there's two problems. By defining zone you might be making it both a variable and a map index. 

Also each map [index] (if thats the right term) should be unique. Here's an example: https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/terraform-variable-map-type-explained/

Comment: I'm afraid I really don't know anything about GCP. You might want to check that you're using an up to date copy of terraform and you might even want to delete .terraform and run terraform init again to redownload your libraries.

Comment: Invalid default value really makes sense when you compare the example against what you have. It probably means that you're (literally) defining the default map wrong.